# How do I setup a Google Cloud Storage bucket to be accessible via the Simple Storage Service (S3) standard?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, amazon-s3

I understand from Google documentation that it's possible for google cloud storage to be accessed via the Simple Storage Service, which is just what I need for a program that supports this. The program only explicitly refers to Amazon S3 storage but in theory if Google Cloud Storage can support the Simple Storage Service, I imagine that my buckets should be accessible.

I'm prompted for the following info in the program I'm using and am not sure where in the Google cloud console admin website I need to go to get this information I need.

[image]

Bucket/Server path I can work out but the "Access key ID" and "Secret Access Key" I am not so sure.  Can someone advise ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/keys-create-delete

Comment: In the left sidebar of the dashboard, click Google Cloud Storage and then Settings. Select the Interoperability tab.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks so much, that did it!  Feel free to write up an answer.